# How to sort by name in a Google Photos collection?

Tags: google-photos

Since Google moved to the new system, I can't figure out how to organize pictures by name like it used to work: https://photos.google.com/collections. There's no item in the menu to sort pictures.

I uploaded new pictures, put them in a new Collection… and now what?

Does someone know?

<sub>Google… didn't help.</sub>

Comment: Yes, it's only able to be done at https://picasaweb.google.com/

Comment: For what it's worth, you can't sort the photos in the Photos Android app, either. I suggest using the "feedback" feature to let Google know this is a feature that you want.

Comment: Google just announced they're closing PicasaWeb. Now, what?

Answer (score 4):

### You cannot sort in Google Photos / Picture Collections.

1. Head to [Picasa Web Albums](https://picasaweb.google.com/), which is just the old Google+ Photos
2. From there, you can sort:

[image]

---

Since **2011**, people have been complaining about this:

- [Is Google going to fix the messy album sorting problem in Google+ Photos?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/picasa/2SQWSkVq2jA)
- [Why can't we sort our photos in Google Photos anymore?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/picasa/Ey_cHIQi61M)